# Display Set Number of Months with cal

Tags: command-line, date, calendar

With the cal command I noticed you can use:

```
cal -3
```

Which displays current month, one before, and one behind. Is there an easy way to show another number? The following doesn't work:

```
cal -5
```

Are the only options single month, 3 months, or full year? Or is there a simple way to show an amount of months above 3 but below 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question. It was so obvious after reading `man cal`.

```
cal -A 4
```

The above displays 5 months, but not in the same way `cal -3` does (with current month in the middle). Instead it starts with the current month and adds 4 ahead.

Comment: `cal -B2 -A2` should give you 5 months with the current month in the middle

Comment: This is true for a *specific* implementation of `cal`, not for all `cal`s (but which?).

Comment: @MichaelHomer I had no idea there were different versions. I'm using ubuntu.